# VideoJS playing video automatically one time only

Tags: video.js

We have a VideoJS video player installed on the front page of our website and finding it quite annoying how it plays every time we visit the front page.

a) We do want it to play automatically

b) Is it possible for it to only play the 1st time a visitor comes and then when they go to the front page again it does not play which would mean that they would need to hit the play button?

Comment: Are you try to use a cookie? I think that is a very simple problem...

Answer (score 0):

As hinted to by Bruno, I would think the best solution for this would be to use some scripting and a browser cookie.

For example, in PHP you could use this instead of the <video> tag:

```
<?php
echo("<video *your parameters*");
$visited=$_COOKIE['seenvideo'];
if ($visited===NULL) {
    setcookie('seenvideo','yes',0);
} else {
    echo(" autoplay");
}
echo (">"); ?>
```

(Replace *your parameters* above as needed) And then use your normal source tags and closure after it.